# Seeking help in deciding correctness of sentences

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I am proof reading my friends resume,

He has written his career Objective as below:

1) Seeking a challenging position in an organization, where my skills and my education background can add value to the growth of the organization and allow development of my skills to organization potential.

I feel the sentence should be rewritten as "....growth of the organization and also allow development of my skills to organization potential".

Second Question: His work experience section is described as below.

2) Currently working as Systems Engineer in XYZ Limited with total experience of 2 years in .NET technology inclusive of 3 months of training.

I feel the sentence should be rewritten as ".... inclusive of 3 months training.".

please help me in deciding, whether my editions are correct or not.

Comment: Both versions of both statements are fine, IMHO. _also_ would be redundant, it doesn't add anything that isn't obvious, but it doesn't hurt. And _of_ can often be omitted from phrases like that.

Comment: As an aside, resumes generally don't need objective statements; they just take up space that could be better used for describing work experience/education.  Also, try to avoid complete sentences/blocks of text.  Judicious use of bullets, indents, and underline/bold/italics goes a long way to make a resume pop.

Comment: @Barmar: You're seriously saying you think *...allow development of my skills to organization potential* is "fine"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think he edited the question after my comment, I don't remember the end of the sentence being like that. I think he also swapped the two versions in his second question, the version with _of_ was what he thought it should be rewritten as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make the following changes:

> I am`[1]` seeking a challenging position in an organization`[2]` where my skills and `[3]` educational`[4]` background can add value to the growth of the organization,`[5]` and allow development of my skills to organization potential.`[6]`

1. Added a verb to the sentence
2. Removed comma
3. Removed redundant *my*
4. Noun *education* changed to the adjective *educational*
5. Added comma
6. "Allow development of my skills to organization potential"... I'm not really sure what he's trying to say here?

> Currently working as Systems Engineer at`[1]` XYZ Limited with a total of 2 years experience`[2]` working with`[3]` .NET technology including`[4]` 3 months of training.

1. *In* changed to *at*, you can work *in* an industry sector but you can only work *at* a company
2. Changed word order
3. You can work *in* .NET, or you can work *with* .NET technology.
4. *Inclusive of* doesn't really fit here. Can't really explain why, it just makes your years of experience sound like you're trying to sell me car insurance.

Comment: "Allow development of my skills to organization potential"... I'm not really sure what he's trying to say here?. By this he meant is the organization should also allow him to grow to a good standard (in this case the organization standard). I think that can be omitted as it does not make much sense.

Comment: @user2900314 Oh! In which case he should say "And allow the development of my skills to reach the organization's standard".

Comment: Oh, yes that would be perfect, thanks a lot, Mark.

Comment: @user2900314 No problem! :)